# different behavior of App in Jasmine tests, based on placement of setting window size

Tags: jasmine, protractor, ionic-framework

I'm utilizing this tutorial http://ramonvictor.github.io/protractor/slides/#/37

So far so good.  The tests set their window size inside the test

**THis Window Size Setting performs well**

```
var width = 375; 
var height = 667;

 describe("login", function () {

    it("should go to login page", function () {
        writeTitleToLog('Login');
        writeToLog("resizing window and going to home page");
        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
        page.getPage('/');
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual("My Title");
        page.takeAScreenShot("blahblahtestfolder/" + screencapCounter + "loginpage_" + width + "x" + height + ".png");
        screencapCounter++;
    });
```

I tried setting the screensize inside `onPrepare()` and the tests fail.. app looks misaligned.  Any ideas why the differing behavior even with the exact same dimensions?

**This Window Size Setting breaks my tests**

```
onPrepare: function () {
    var path = require('path');
    var folderName = path.join(__dirname,"blahblahtests");
    var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
    mkdirp(folderName, function(err) {
        if(err){
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log("successfully created " + folderName);
        }
    });
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(375, 667);
}
```

Using this `onPrepare()` method makes the HTML/CSS perform unexpectedly .. for instance my menu is now out of the visible frame, whereas with the first method it worked fine.

Comment: May be it is more about how your application under tests react on window size changes?..

Comment: I guess, but I'm unsure where to start looking.. I guess I'll just ignore trying to set window sizes in `onPrepare()` , and instead pass the dimensions as a parameter to the first test